# how to upload multipart request using retrofit library?

Tags: java, android, json, spring-mvc, retrofit

i have a web service controller calss like this

```
public class User {
    private String customer; // JSON string
    private CommonsMultipartFile photo1;
    private CommonsMultipartFile photo2;
    private CommonsMultipartFile photo3;
    private CommonsMultipartFile photo4;
    public User() {}
    public User(String customer, CommonsMultipartFile photo1, CommonsMultipartFile photo2, 
            CommonsMultipartFile photo3,CommonsMultipartFile photo4) { 
        this.customer = customer; this.photo1= photo1; this.photo2= photo2; 
        this.photo3= photo3; this.photo4= photo4;}
    public String getCustomer() { return customer; }
    public CommonsMultipartFile getPhoto1() { return Photo1; }
    public CommonsMultipartFile getPhoto2() { return Photo2; }
    public CommonsMultipartFile getPhoto3() { return Photo3; }
    public CommonsMultipartFile getPhoto4() { return Photo4; }
}    


    @RequestMapping(value = "/create",method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<String> createCustomerWithKYC(User user) throws Exception {
            CustomerWSDto customerWSDto = new JSONDeserializer<CustomerWSDto>().use(null, CustomerWSDto.class).deserialize(user.getCustomer());
    Customer customer = customerAssem.fromDto(customerWSDto);
    CustomerDto customerDto = customerAssem.toDto(customer);
    customerDto.getphoto1().setphoto1(user.photo1);
    customerDto.getphoto1().setphoto2(user.photo2);
    customerDto.getphoto1().setphoto3(user.photo3);
    customerDto.getphoto1().setphoto4(user.photo4);
    customerService.createCustomer(customerDto);
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(new JSONSerializer().exclude("*.class").serialize(customerDto), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

the above create() method accepts object of type User.

In client app i am calling this webservice like bellow using retrofit

```
@Multipart
    @POST("/create")
    void createUser(@Part("user") User user,
                               @PartMap Map<String,TypedFile> files,
                               Callback<Customer> callback);
```

But it is giving me no defaut constructor found at controller class in server side. Please check where i am doing wrong. Please solve this problem.

Comment: "Please solve this problem". We're not gonna give you code and that's it.

Comment: create User class as a simple POJO, with empty constructor and provide setter and getter for all properties.

Comment: I provided all setter and getter. but I didn't showed here. Because it is understood. Is there any thing wrong in my client side. that is multipart request?

Answer (score 0):

Create User class as a simple POJO, with empty constructor and provide setter and getter for all properties.

````
public class User {
    private String user; // JSON string
    private CommonsMultipartFile photo1;
    private CommonsMultipartFile photo2;
    private CommonsMultipartFile photo3;
    private CommonsMultipartFile photo4;

    Public user(){}

    Public CommonsMultipartFile getPhoto1(){
        return photo1;
    }

    Public setPhoto1(CommonsMultipartFile photo1){
        this.photo1 = photo1;
    }

    ...

}
```
````

Comment: I think Setters are not required. Because in created() already have a object of User type..